# How to define a Loopcut into a specific area?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode

I want to make a Loopcut only in the Torso area, not in the chin, How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Move your cursor to an edge perpendicular to your desired cut.  Keep moving your mouse to the middle of a vertical edge near the torso for this particular example, the cutting line indicator will change direction.

Comment: Can you explain in more details? I'm a begginer.

Comment: you 'll have to change the topology to make the loop cut follow another direction

Comment: Can you explain in more details? I'm a begginer, and English is not my lenguage.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OszPcbecX50  Tutorial Video on another site.

Comment: But the video doesnt answer my question.

Comment: I want a loopcut only in the torso

Answer (score 2):

If you have the model with mirror modifier, select all the faces that you want the loopcut to go through, then hit <kbd>I</kbd> shortcut to inset the faces and <kbd>B</kbd> shortcut after that to disable boundary of the inset.

[image]

[image]

If you have the mirror modifier already applied, use the same method while selecting the faces from both sides from the center.

[image]